# Getting the response of a post web api call

Tags: powerapps

I'm creating a custom connector for powerapps but I'm stuck on deserializing/consuming the response from my web api call.

I have tested the Get and it works great, but when I tried to Post. Nothing is getting printed, I'm guessing it's something to do with accessing the variable.

I tested it on the "Connections" and I found this is the default response I got when I call it:

```
Body:
{
  "GetPostTestResult": "This is your Project: "
}
```

While the response on my get is just the string "Hello World"

So how can I access "GetPostTestResult"

Also a follow up question, what if I have a list of complex objects, how will I able to access them?

Example response would be:

```
{
  "url": "asd",
  "key": "asd",
  "customFields": [
    {
      "Name": "asd",
      "Value": "asd"
    },
    {
      "Name": "asd",
      "Value": "asd"
    },
    {
      "Name": "asd",
      "Value": "asd"
    }
  ]
}
```